# Can sail be fixed or simple aerodynamic shape split?

Tags: drag, aerodynamics

Is it possible to create small shape that would be aerodynamic in most directions and not much in one of (kind of fixed sail) ?

Performed some experiments with pyramid like shape in front of bike (simple fairing) and found it can help also a bit in backwind, but remaining angles are unwanted.
Returned to basic simulations trying to split fairing to smaller oriented parts to reduce bad angle wind problems (under bottom line).

At the end maybe found something smaller than streamlined which seems to be quite aerodynamic (in case I can trust this basic simulation).
I used multiple colors to place elements on its positions, but simulation is BW, so ellipses are not part of tested shape.

**Is there any standard way to split basic aerodynamic shapes or create bigger compositions from separate parts ?**

[image: Shapes and simulation]

Simulations tested by https://physics.weber.edu/schroeder/fluids